# Failed to bind to CoreCLR

Tags: .net, .net-core, debian-stretch

I'm attempting to deploy a Framwork-Dependant .Net Core app to Debian 9 Stretch, but when I launch the .net app it throws the error:

```
>     Failed to load ▒݅, error: libunwind.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>     Failed to bind to CoreCLR at '/var/www/html/libcoreclr.so'
```

Yes, the file is at /var/www/html/libcoreclr.so

Comment: Same as [this bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23641).  The completely corrupted name is pretty unhealthy.

Answer (score 8):

This has similar root cause as https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3390

For anyone who is not as experienced in Linux, installing `libunwind` can be done in Debian and derivative distributions (Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Devuan, ...) by executing

`sudo apt install libunwind8`

For any RedHat like distributions:

`sudo yum install libunwind`

Answer (score 2):

`libunwind8` is listed into `.net` core prerequisites under Ubuntu, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x).

I experienced same issue under Debian 9 and I solved installing the lib via packet manager.
Hope this helps.